Finding equation of line of intersection of two planes
Suppose I have two planes whose equations are $\vec{r} . \vec{n_1} = 1$ and $\vec{r} . \vec{n_2} = 1$
I am willing to find the equation of their line of intersection in the vector form directly in terms of $n_1$ and $n_2$, where $ \vec{n_1}\times \vec{n_2}≠0$.
The direction vector of the line of intersection is pretty much $\vec{n_1}\times \vec{n_2}$. However I am unable to find out one more point on that line of intersection so that I can write the vector form of the line of intersection. How do I proceed?

Sure.@KaleBhodre

You assumed tacitely that $n_1,n_2$ are linearly independent, i.e.
$$\|n_1\|^2\|n_2\|^2-(n_1\cdot n_2)^2>0.$$
I leave it to you to solve the Cramer system
$$(a n_1+bn_2)\cdot n_1=(a n_1+bn_2)\cdot n_2=1.$$
